# xml parsing in firefox not working

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox

I have a xml file whose content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ReturnMessage>
<root>ReturnMessage</root>
<cancelMessage>Request cancelled.  /cancelMessage>
<confirmMessage>Click 'Create Document' to continue.</confirmMessage>
</ReturnMessage>
```

I load my xml like this

```
var result = responseText;
if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
    alert("firefox");
    xml=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
    xml.load(result);
}
```

When execute the below code

```
var cnfmMsgCnt = xml.getElementsByTagName("confirmMessage");
alert(cnfmMsgCnt.lenght);
```

it alerts a 0 is firefox.

```
var displayMsg = xml.getElementsByTagName("confirmMessage").item(0).text
```

also does not provide any output in FF.

It works perfect in IE but it is not working in Firefox.

Comment: Please note how much easier and cleaner the four-space-indent code formatting is to both read and write. Check the source code to see how I did what I did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `load()` takes a file name as argument, not an XML string.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.load  (and more normative: [W3C DOM Level 3 Load & Save module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-LS-20030619/load-save.html#LS-DocumentLS))

What you probably want is explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

```
var sMyString = "<a id=\"a\"><b id=\"b\">hey!<\/b><\/a>";
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(sMyString, "text/xml");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working now and also I learnt about loading XML